# Date conversion in MS SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to MS SQL Server so would want a very simple explanation on the following.

My question is create a view with customer_id, date_of_birth, age_in_months(convert the difference in age in months (age_in_months = getdate() - DOB)) from the `customer` table.

The date of birth (DOB) is available in the `customer` table for each `customer_id`.

I want to create a view taking 
Create view as

```
select customer_id, dob, Convert(INT, DATEDIFF(DAY, DOB,GETDATE())*(12.0/365.0)) AS Age_in__Months
from customer
```

Secondly how do I join this view with another view created name for eg cust1 to combine display everything in a single view?

Something like create view combined:

```
select * from cust
```

and join it to:

```
select * from cust 1
```

Comment: Please show the DDL of the tables.

Comment: Age in months is actually a bit tricky. The obvious way to check this is `DateDiff(month, DOB, Getdate())`, but this gives incorrect answers for most cases. For example, if the DOB was 2018-07-31, using the DateDiff check above results in an age of 1 month, when there is actually only 8 days difference. Varying last day of month values can confound what you really want as well, depending on your specifications. The simplest method I know is: `DateDiff(month, DOB, Getdate()) - CASE WHEN DatePart(Day, DOB) < DatePart(Day, GetDate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: I use the following to create a view 
create view cust as
(
select customer_Id, DOB, (DateDiff(month, DOB, Getdate()) - CASE WHEN DatePart(Day, DOB) < DatePart(Day, GetDate()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as dob_in_months
from Customer
)

It say completed successfully 

Then I try running the view
Select * from cust;


It returns the following
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: is DOB a character field????

Comment: There's really no such thing as "age in months" unless you arbitrarily redefine "month" as 365/12, which would give you an answer, but nothing related to actual months. As for your second question, you can use a view anywhere you could use a table, however there is usually a performance hit. For example if your view is CustView, you could do SELECT Cust.dob from Cust INNER JOIN CustView on CustView.customer_id= Cust.customer_id

Comment: - Cetin - it is in format dd/mm/yy
customer_Id DOB Gender city_code
268408 02-01-1970 M 4

Comment: - Terry got the second part correctly .

For the first part where you said 'There's really no such thing as "age in months" unless you arbitrarily redefine "month" as 365/12, which would give you an answer, but nothing related to actual months'

Do i have to use declare and set ?

Comment: side note, nested views perform terribly and make debugging tricky... they are prone to breaking, especially when you do select * since any DDL could cause errors, column name conflicts, etc.

Comment: @scsimon How do i go about it then ? What is the best possible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

Sounds like a simple join...

```
SELECT 
    c.*,
    c2.*
FROM Cust c
INNER JOIN Cust2 c2
  ON c.customer_id = c2.customer_id
```